# Android/Java: failure passing Canvas as a class constructor parameter

Tags: java, android, canvas, constructor

In the GraphicsView class's onDraw method I make an instance of the Plotter class, but the constructor does not set the in-class Canvas field

We start here

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Plotter plotter = new Plotter(1, canvas);
}
```

..and go to Plotter to create an instance of it:

```
Plotter (int dotsPerPx, Canvas canvas_) {
    this.dotsPerPx = dotsPerPx;
    this.canvas = canvas_;
}

int dotsPerPx;  //This one gets set to 1, as supposed
Canvas canvas;  //And this remains null, though canvas_==openGLCanvas{...}
int screenWidth = canvas.getWidth();  //NullPointerException!
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas is not instantiated yet. Use this:

```
Plotter (int dotsPerPx, Canvas canvas_) {
    this.dotsPerPx = dotsPerPx;
    this.canvas = canvas_;
    screenWidth = canvas.getWidth();
}

int dotsPerPx;  //This one sets to 1, as supposed
Canvas canvas;  //And this remains null, though canvas_==openGLCanvas...
int screenWidth;
```

Basically, all the code outside constructor and methods (fields creation, initializer blocks) is executed *before* constructor is called. So `int screenWidth = canvas.getWidth();` tries to call method on field which is null (by default, unless you specify something else) because constructor wasn't called yet.